# box.com api - redirect Location - security

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, box

I am experimenting with the box.com api, and using my developer access code, I can retrieve folder info, file info, etc.

When I try to get a file's content, I see that box.com issues a 302 header, with a very long URL on dl.boxcloud.com.

Is that link accessible to everyone on the internet?

The link appears to be unique per api call, but how long are those links valid for?

This seems to be a bit of a security hole, I need an access token to make the api call, but the link the api returns is not protected?

Comment: It appears that the 302 links do time out, but I would like to know how long they are in scope for.

Comment: Is there an API call that can invalidate the long URL. If there was, I could delete it once I had retrieved the document from box.com.